# Why does ntpdate -q 127.0.0.1 give any offset error?

Tags: ntp

When I run `ntpdate -q 127.0.0.1` I get:

```
server 127.0.0.1, stratum 3, offset -0.000013, delay 0.02573
28 Apr 17:30:41 ntpdate[27944]: adjust time server 127.0.0.1 offset -0.000013 sec
```

Why does it register an offset of -0.000013 sec considering the comparison is to its own system time? Shouldn't it be 0.0 offset and delay?

Comment: Maybe it takes 13µs to send and receive a data packet through the network stack?